# NuGet package refuses to uninstall in .NET Core library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating a .NET Core xUnit test project library in VS2017. I accidentally installed the System.Collections.Immutable NuGet package, and now I want to uninstall it.

- First, I tried editing the `csproj` file and removing this line:

  ```
  <PackageReference Include="System.Collections.Immutable" Version="1.3.1" />
  ```
- That didn't work, since the types from that package were still highlighted in the editor. So I tried running `Uninstall-Package System.Collections.Immutable` in the Package Manager Console.
- The console said it couldn't find the package, so I tried putting the `<PackageReference...` line above back and running `Uninstall-Package` again. The console said the uninstall succeeded, but VS still recognized the types.
- I tried closing VS, deleting `.vs/`, and reopening. It still recognized the types.
- I tried git stashing my changes, running `git clean -xdf`, and running `dotnet restore` from the command line. Somehow, it still outputs

  ```
  $ dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for C:\cygwin64\home\james\Code\cs\BlockList\src\BlockList\BlockList.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\cygwin64\home\james\Code\cs\BlockList\src\BlockList.Tests\BlockList.Tests.csproj...
  ...
  Installing System.Collections.Immutable 1.2.0.
  Installing System.Collections.Immutable 1.3.0.
  ...
  ```
- I also tried restoring from Visual Studio instead of the command line. Still no luck.

When I searched all the files in my repo for the word `Immutable`, the only thing popping up is `project.assets.json` in the `obj` directory. Not a single source file contains the word `Immutable`. I'm confused, then, as to how it's still being referenced. How can I uninstall it?

A few other things:

- I checked the 'Dependencies' drop-down for my project in Solution Explorer, and it's not listed there.
- I don't want to delete my local copy of the repo and re-clone it, since I have other work stashed.
- `System.Collections.Immutable.dll` doesn't show up at all in the `bin/` directory, yet when I use one of the types in my library and run it, it works fine.

Thanks!

**edit:** Adding this line to the library:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeof(ImmutableArrayExtensions).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location);
```

And running it says that the assembly is located in this location:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.1.2\System.Collections.Immutable.dll
```

Comment: Is there another package that depends on `System.Collections.Immutable`?

Comment: @DavidG No, no other packages depend on it.

Comment: So you've checked every other reference and see that none of them depend on it?

Comment: @DavidG Yes I have.

Comment: Even transitive dependencies? So packageX depends on packageY that depends on that one?

Comment: Can you list all installed packages via Nuget?

Comment: Everyone, I posted an answer to my question. tldr, I overlooked the dependency even though I looked at `Microsoft.NETCore.App` twice.

Comment: So basically my first comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After about an hour, I found out what the problem was. My .NET Core library referenced `Microsoft.NETCore.App`, which referenced `System.Collections.Immutable`. I looked at the dependencies for the former, but overlooked `System.Collections.Immutable` because that package references maybe 50 other packages. I ended up finding this out by creating a brand-new xUnit test project, and trying to see if `ImmutableArray<>` was present without installing anything. Sure enough, I could use it out of the box.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Done. I had to wait 2 days before I could accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with VS2017 and a different nuget package that wouldn't fully uninstall.  I ultimately had to create a new project and cut and paste all my code into it.  Kind of a sledge hammer approach, but faster than crawling through dependencies.